# How to set up docker-compose containers for gRPC TLS connection?

Tags: go, docker-compose, grpc

I have a **gRPC** client and a server as two docker containers declared with docker-compose.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  apiserver:
    image: golang:latest
    container_name: apiserver
    expose:
      - "3000"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: go run cmd/apiserver/main.go

  userserver:
    image: golang:latest
    container_name: userserver
    expose:
      - "3001"
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    command: go run cmd/userserver/main.go
```

I omitted some things like volumes etc as I think they are not related to the issue.

When a client tries to dial server I get an error `TLS handshake error from 172.22.0.1:34824: tls: oversized record received with length 21536`

server (**userserver**):

```
lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "userserver:3001")
if err != nil {
    logger.Critical(ctx, "failed to listen: %v", err)
}

grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
userServer := userserver.New()
pb.RegisterDomainServer(grpcServer, userServer)
rpcErr := grpcServer.Serve(lis)

if rpcErr != nil {
    logger.Critical(ctx, "failed to serve: %v", rpcErr)
}
```

client (**apiserver**):

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("userserver:3001", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer conn.Close()

client := pb.NewDomainClient(conn)
_, err = client.Dispatch(ctx, &pb.Command{
    Name:    command,
    Payload: payload,
})
```

### Info

the client is `apiserver` and the `userserver` is gRPC server, the reason why client is called `apiserver` is because it also works as http proxy. So the  `apiserver` container tries to dial `userserver` container

Comment: Why are you listening to userip from server? `lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "userserver:3001")` Server should be registered to it's own ip and/or port. [More info net pkg](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#pkg-overview)

Comment: And when you dial it should be `apiserver:port`

Comment: the client is `apiserver` and the `userserver` is gRPC server, the reason why client is called `apiserver` is because it also works as http proxy. So the  `apiserver` container tries to dial `userserver ` container

Comment: `WithInsecure` disables transport security.

Comment: Ye but I think I need it right ? I am not using any certs, just want to make it work atm

Comment: When it says it disables transport security, it really means it: no TLS, no TLS handshake, etc.... it's just plaintext. If you want to skip cert verification, you need to pass a `tls.Config` object with `InsecureSkipVerify`. Your server is expecting a `ClientHello` message and getting some random request.

Comment: and can I make server to not expect hello message ? I mean how to I make server work with client `WithInsecure`

Comment: Then you need to make the server insecure as well. But your whole question is about using TLS, so just pass a tls config to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `grpc.Creads(...)`

We are use this code:

```
package main

import(
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "io/ioutil"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
    "mysource.com/packages/grpcserver"
)

func main(){
    cert := "/path/to/cert.crt"
    key := "/path/to/cert.key"
    caCrt := "/path/to/my.ca"

    certificate, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(cert, key)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }   
    certPool := x509.NewCertPool()

    ca, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caCrt)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    if ok := certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(ca); !ok {
        return
    }
    creds := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{
        ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{certificate},
        ClientCAs:    certPool,
        MinVersion:   tls.VersionTLS12,
    })

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(creds))
    server := grpcserver.NewGrpcServer()
    grpcserver.RegisterGrpcServer(grpcServer, server)

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:11311")      
    log.Fatal(grpcServer.Serve(lis))
}
```

Comment: but I do not want to use any certificates, or is it impossible with tls ?

Comment: You can fill in the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) fields as you like. Eg: `InsecureSkipVerify` to disable all certificate checks.

Comment: @Marc right. You can use like this `creds := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{ ClientAuth:   tls.InsecureSkipVerify})`

Comment: i've set `creds := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}) grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(creds))` on server and `creds := credentials.NewTLS(&tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}) conn, err := grpc.Dial("userserver:3001", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))` But still same error

Comment: For client, need use too `credntials.TLS{}` and in `tls.Config` need set `ServerName: yourName`. You can see in [this](https://bbengfort.github.io/programmer/2017/03/03/secure-grpc.html)

Comment: for client or server ? because for client it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: And for client and for server.

Comment: so for client i pass server host as ServerName and for server the client host ?

Comment: @Sah4ez @Marc could you guys as well explain please why it this simplest example [here](https://medium.com/pantomath/how-we-use-grpc-to-build-a-client-server-system-in-go-dd20045fa1c2) setup using `WithInsecure` works and in my case it does not ?

Comment: but it doesn't :( in this case i do not think the tls config or WithInsecure is a problem, there has to be something with my docker-compose setup